# Why is Push notifications required for GPS to work?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, notifications

How are they related? How is Push notifications used in iPhone Maps application?

After jailbreaking my Push notifications and GPS are not working. I know I can install Pushfix from Cydia but it costs money but my question is why? Why should I fix Push for GPS to work.

iPhone 3G on iOS 4.2.1 unlocked with iPad baseband 6.15.00

Comment: Or, you could undo the jailbreak and have it all working. At no cost.

Comment: Can't. I am using it in India. I can use it only after unlock.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, they are not related. If I turn off push, either on my jailbroken iphone or my girl's unjailbroken one, GPS and maps keep on working just fine.

**edit:** Reading little bit more on [pushfix](http://www.pushfix.info/notifications) I'll try to explain what became clear to me.

Push and Maps or GPS are still unrelated.

Jailbreaking is a legal procedure to make your iPhone free from "apple locks". That's where the name came from.

With that, a jailbroken iPhone can do things apple doesn't allow, but without a proper tool installed "jailbreaking" does nothing.

**pushfix** is a tool to fix a problem on the push notifications brought by activating the iphone without an authorized SIM (a.k.a. Hacktivated iPhone). *pushfix* was further improved to fix other problems, probably brought by the same Hacktivation, such as Wifi and GPS.

I *highly* recommend you do a lot more research and get familiarized with the terms and issues related to iPhone (yes, that's **a lot of reading** and quite complicated) or just get an Android! ;)

Here are some good starting points (other than the link already provided):

- http://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+jailbreaking
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jailbreak+iphone

And some good sources:

- http://thebigboss.org/jailbreak-now
- http://blog.iphone-dev.org/ (very technical and complicated)

Comment: Then, why do people install Pushfix to have working GPS after jailbreaking?

Comment: @Manish my point on the answer is that I never heard of such thing and I agree on your awkwardness about it. They shouldn't be related as much as they seem to not be related to me, from everything I ever saw about iPhones. ... (some time passed) ... Reading about pushfix on http://www.pushfix.info/notifications I can see now your problem is about hacking iphone activation and that "pushfix" is a generic tool that fix that along with issues that hacking brings.